# regex not repeating dot character javascript

Tags: javascript, regex

I have come up my regex in javascript `^[a-zA-Z0-9.]+([.][a-zA-Z0-9]+)$` which I am trying to filter out string.

- No dot character at the begin nor end
- dot character can be middle of other Alphabet letter or numbers
- If dot character cannot be appear more than twice

These are my expected pass cases

- foo.bar
- f.o.o
- foo.bar.foo
- fo.123.321

These are my expected No-pass cases

- .foo
- .foo.
- foo.
- foo..bar
- .foo.bar

I feel like I am very close(or not at all). How can I filter out dot repeating dot characters? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think that's what you looking for:

```
/^([a-zA-Z0-9]+\.)+([a-zA-Z0-9]+)$/
```

**Tests**

expected pass cases

```
/^([a-zA-Z0-9]+\.)+([a-zA-Z0-9]+)$/.test('foo.bar') // true
/^([a-zA-Z0-9]+\.)+([a-zA-Z0-9]+)$/.test('f.o.o') // true
/^([a-zA-Z0-9]+\.)+([a-zA-Z0-9]+)$/.test('foo.bar.foo') // true
/^([a-zA-Z0-9]+\.)+([a-zA-Z0-9]+)$/.test('fo.123.321') // true
```

Expected No-pass cases

```
/^([a-zA-Z0-9]+\.)+([a-zA-Z0-9]+)$/.test('.foo') // false
/^([a-zA-Z0-9]+\.)+([a-zA-Z0-9]+)$/.test('.foo.') // false
/^([a-zA-Z0-9]+\.)+([a-zA-Z0-9]+)$/.test('foo.') // false
/^([a-zA-Z0-9]+\.)+([a-zA-Z0-9]+)$/.test('foo..bar') // false
/^([a-zA-Z0-9]+\.)+([a-zA-Z0-9]+)$/.test('.foo.bar') // false
```